# background task interval period in IOS 7

Tags: ios, ios7

I Have the following code in the appdidEnterBackground() and I see that in IOS 6 I see that the background time period is approx 10 mins and the same code in IOS 7 is printing 2 mins.

Here's the code:

```
-(void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{        

backgroundTaskIdentifier = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:backgroundTaskIdentifier];
            backgroundTaskIdentifier = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;

         }];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

            NSTimeInterval timeInterval = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] backgroundTimeRemaining];


            NSLog(@" time remaining in background = %f",timeInterval);
 });
}
```

Question is: How can I increase my background time period from 2 mins to approx 10 mins in IOS 7? Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: Read the iOS 7 release notes. This is the new behavior. You can't change it.

Comment: The WWDC videos also cover this topic.

Comment: Dont know how I missed this. Thanks

Comment: Don't worry about this thing, App goes to sleep but It won't terminate the background process, it just awakes the process when the phone resume using :)

Comment: It's exactly 180s so 3min (and not 2min) :)

Comment: Yep, as @Gros stated, it's 3min in iOS7.

Comment: Where can I find the official documentation stated iOS 7 only gives 3 mins (aside from WWDC videos)? Thanks.

Comment: @Wain could you let us know which video covers that? thx

Answer (score 1):

> Read the iOS 7 release notes. This is the new behavior. You can't
>   change it. ([rmaddy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1226963/rmaddy))
>   
> It's exactly 180s so 3min (and not 2min) :) ([Gros](https://stackoverflow.com/users/428606/gros))

**Note**

For the sake of maintaining order, I followed the answer for this question: [What to do with questions that have been self-resolved as a comment instead of an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117251/what-to-do-with-questions-that-have-been-self-resolved-as-a-comment-instead-of-a)
(marked as community wiki)