# Running the application in background for 10 mins

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, background, uibackgroundtask

I am working on streams.
I want the stream should be open for 10 minutes in background and after 10 minutes I want to close it. 
I have done like this...

```
`__block UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier bgTask;
    bgTask = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
        [application endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
        bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    }];

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
      [self resumeStream];
});`
```

In this case The application is running only for 3 mins in backgroun and after that Its disconnecting.

Comment: Make your stream timeout for 10 mint in background

Comment: @AsifHabib It is not running for 10 mins. It;s only running for 3 mins

Comment: There must be a timeout for stream! if stream is disconnected background task can do nothing! so you must have to set timeout of your stream as well!

Comment: This is the new behavior for IOS7. Please read release note for ios7

Comment: @DareDevil What do you mean?

Comment: @DareDevil I have changed it to `CGFloat delayInSeconds = 2*60.0;
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
        dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
            [self startClient];
        });` but still of no use.

Comment: You will get approximately 3 min to finish long background task from ios 7.

Comment: @DareDevil Yes. even my application is for iOS7 and above only. But I need 10 mins. How can I do that. Is it possible to do?

Comment: Not possible in normal mode. In voip mode its possible to keep connection alive. But if your app does not have voip functionality , apple will reject it.

Comment: @DareDevil But I am not using any of those listed services. I have get to know that if I mention any of those modes adn if I don't use those in application it might be possible to reject the application by Apple.

Comment: @DareDevil interesting - I haven't tested. I can't find any official documentation saying they changed the old 10 min to 3mins?

Answer (score 0):

The maximum background time has changed from 10 minutes in iOS 6 to 3 minutes in iOS 7.

See [background task interval period in IOS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18815384/background-task-interval-period-in-ios-7)